# mismatched anonymous define() module typescript with AMD and export module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013, requirejs, amd

I am trying to create an application using Typescript(1.7.5) and AMD module. I have added reference to r.js and requirejs.js. below is my TS code:

```
export module TestNs {
    export class TestClass {
        public fn(): void{
            debugger;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my aspx page to call "fn()":

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TypeScriptPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.TypeScriptPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="div1">
        </div>
        <script src="Scripts/r.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/TypeScriptBegin.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var testObj = new TestNs.TestClass();
            testObj.fn();

        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but I am getting below errors:

**TestNS is undefined**

**"JavaScript runtime error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports)"**

however when I remove ***"export"*** keyword, above code works fine. I am new to Typescript and requirejs. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should remove the following line:

```
export module TestNs
```

Every file in type script is a module, so you do not need that part.

EDIT

Then in your javascript remove script tag to load your class and use something like this:

```
var moduleName = 'Scripts/TypeScriptBegin';
require([moduleName], function(TestNs){
            var testObj = new TestNs.TestClass();
            testObj.fn();
})
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: If I remove "export" keyword then also it works correctly because then its now creating "define("require","exports",require,exports)" tag but then the code wont be using requirejs to load any dependency at run time. And when I modified the code as per your suggestion, I got below error:0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Module name "Scripts/TypeScriptBegin" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Comment: again one more question, if I remove 'export module TestNs' then should the second line be using TestNs? and also when will debugger in fn be hit?

Comment: No you should not. You will assign name to the module when you import it. In case of requirejs - it is name of the parameter passed in the function(TestNs). I have tested the code above in latest chrome - debugger will stop upon loading the page.

Comment: Okay. thanks for helping out. By trial and error, I found an extension to your suggestion which uses 'export module ModName'. please see answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amid, I found an answer(incase any body needs in future):

TypeScriptBegin.ts

```
export module TestNs {
    export class TestClass {
        public fn(): void {
            //var v = new TSTest.TSTest.TestClass();
            debugger;
            //v.fn();
        }
    }
}
```

call from aspx:

```
<script src="Scripts/r.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var moduleName = 'Scripts/TypeScriptBegin';
            require([moduleName], function (TestMod) {
                var testObj = new TestMod.TestNs.TestClass();
                testObj.call();
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Have a look at the section 'needless namespacing' here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md#needless-namespacing

Comment: Nice info, it was worth reading for so many points. but the app I am developing is already existing and so huge that I will have to use modules.