# How to use RequiresJs to load typescript module (asp.net mvc/visual studio environment)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, typescript, requirejs

Let's say I have 2 files: `test1.ts` and `test2.ts`. This is the content of test1:

```
export const x = 1
```

This is the content of test1:

```
import { x } from './test2'

alert(x);
```

When I run the application, I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at test1.js:2`.

According to other posts, this error is caused by the fact that web browsers don't support `export`, and `require(...)`. To solve it, one of the solution would be to use something like **RequireJs**.

So I've done some readings. [This article](http://blog.novanet.no/making-requirejs-play-nice-with-asp-net-mvc/) has been the easiest for me to understand.

1. I've added this line in the **_Layout.cshtml** file.

   `<script src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>`
2. Create a config file.

   ```
   requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: '/Scripts/js'
   });
   ```
3. I've put **test1** and **test2** in the `/Scripts/js` folder.
4. Run the application, but still get the same error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at test1.js:2`.

How to fix the error using **RequireJs**?

Thanks for helping.

## EDIT

The solution doesn't have to be RequireJs but anything the fix the problem. There are so many great tutorial on `typescript`, but they all assume that people are using node or angularjs. All I need is to add some typescript to my asp.net mvc app. As long it was one file, things were fine. Now I'd like to re-use some of the code, thus I organized them in different files. Unfortunately, I can't move forward because of that error. I've been sitting there for 3 days now.

## EDIT 2

I've added commonJs to amd as you suggested by `@artem`,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "module": "amd",
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "removeComments": true,
     "preserveConstEnums": true,
     "sourceMap": true
 }
```

}

now I'm getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() 
module: function (require, exports, CommonTypes_1) {
//...
```

It seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module) is dealing with the same issue. Should I put this code in a new file?

Comment: `exports is not defined` error indicates that you compile `test1.ts` and `test2.ts` with default, `module=CommonJS` option. For RequireJS, you have to use `module=AMD` in compiler options.

Comment: @artem, please see `EDIT.`

Comment: I found another similar question, it seems like it has working answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930285/mismatched-anonymous-define-module-typescript-with-amd-and-export-module

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little old, but just ran into this problem.  Here's how I solved it.

This post was very helpful:  https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/05/27/Adding-RequireJS-to-an-ASPNET-MVC-project

First, add require.js to your BundleConfig.cs.  Mine looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/require.js"));
```

Next, make sure _Layout.cshtml renders "scripts" section after your bundles.  Mine looks like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then in your view, render the scripts section like below.  My Index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        require(["Scripts/Init"],
            function (Init) {
                Init.Start();
            }
        );
    </script>
}
```

My ~/Scripts/Init.ts file looks like this:

```
import * as DataBind from "./DataBind"

export function Start() {
    DataBind.SetAllDatabinds(null);
}
```

From there, you can load in all your modules as needed.  The important thing I found is to not have any "loose code" in your TypeScript files (i.e. the "alert(x)" in the example).  Everything should be exported.